# 301 redirect FOR (and not with) a js script

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have to redirect a js script, I've tried with a 301 definition in htaccess but it doesn't work. I find everywhere how redirect pages with js, but not how redirect js. 
I've a system that the users have to install on the personal device that call the online js file and now I have changed the server and I have to redirect all the request for the old js. Thanks

Comment: So, your new script is on another domain or the filename has changed?

Comment: Do you have the level access to install and/or execute mod_rewrite rules? EDIT: For that matter, are you running apache?

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi: I have to know how do both.

Comment: @JohnGiotta it's only an Hosting service, so I've not much permissions

Answer (score 2):

If you have changed the domain. Use this `.htaccess` file in your previous domains document root.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect JS file 
# If someone enters  http://olddomain.com/old.js in the browser it will be 
# redirected to http://newdomain.com/scripts/script.js file
RewriteRule ^old.js$ http://newdomain.com/scripts/script.js [R=301,L]

# Redirect domain
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, now I'm testing it redirecting to a new script in the same folder on the same domain: the link of my test page is [this](http://www.cattanisimone.it/test/target.html). If you look the code it includes the script1.js file and I'm trying to redirect it to script2.js file.

Comment: It wont work if you test it on the same domain but different path. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.domain.com` prohibits this

Comment: I've tested it on a different domain but it still doesn't work

Comment: I've added the .htaccess content like a comment in the page that I've linked before, now, with this htaccess setting all my site goes down

Comment: The order of the rules were wrong. I fixed it. See update. it should work now. I have tested.

Comment: Updated but when I upload the new .htaccess my site goes down, I've updated the code that I've putted in htaccess like comment in target.html